# Как правильно настроить XMLReader

Tags: php, xml

Здравствуйте, не могу правильно понять работу XMLReader, есть структура следующая:

```
<section id="Ц014790">
    <name>АРХИВ</name>
    <item id="1">
        <NAME>Name 1</NAME>
    </item>
    <item id="2">
        <NAME>Name 2</NAME>
    </item>
    <item id="3">
        <NAME>Name 3</NAME>
    </item>
</section>
<section id="2">
    <name>АРХИВ</name>
    <item id="4">
        <NAME>Name 1</NAME>
    </item>
    <item id="5">
        <NAME>Name 2</NAME>
    </item>
    <item id="6">
        <NAME>Name 3</NAME>
    </item>
</section>
```

Делаю дальше следующее:

```
 $z = new XMLReader;
       $z->open('file.xml');

       $doc = new DOMDocument;


       while ($z->read() && $z->name !== 'item');

       while ($z->name === 'item')
       {
           $node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($z->expand(), true));

           print_r($node->NAME); 

           $z->next('item');
       }
```

в итоге я получаю 3 узла item, а должен получать 6. Поправьте пожалуйста.

Comment: у вас, минимум, невалидный `xml`... у двух тегов нет открывающего значка `NAME>` ..... а еще корня документа нет... странно что вообще работает ... а если следовать примеру отсюда: http://i.kenfin.ru/article/parsim-xml-s-pomoschju-xmlreader  то достаточно написать  `while($z->read()) {
  if($z->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
   if($z->localName == 'NAME') {
    $z->read();
    if($z->nodeType == XMLReader::TEXT) {
                    echo $z->value;
                }     
   }
  }
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Вы объединили два **while** в один в

```
while ($z->read() && $z->name !== 'item');
```

И обрабатываете остановки после первой секции.

```
$z = new XMLReader;
$z->open('file.xml');
$doc = new DOMDocument;

while ($z->read()) // go to next element
{
   while($z->name !== 'item'); // skip not 'item' elements

   while ($z->name === 'item') // process 'item' nodes
   {
       $node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($z->expand(), true));
       print_r($node->NAME); 
       $z->next('item');
   }
}
```